# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'AzurePlugin' has already been declared on line 1, which is a comment

Tags: javascript, class

In my code, I was creating a class named `AzurePlugin`, but my browser (Google Chrome, Version 86.0.4240.75 x86_64) returned an error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'AzurePlugin' has already been declared`. But, it said that the error was from Line 1, which is a comment. I already tried to check if a class named `AzurePlugin` already exists, but it doesn't. Even this error is still there, the code *still runs as intended*. Here is some of the code, and if you need more, go to https://azurejs.alexdacoder.repl.co/.

```js
//////////////////////////   << Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'AzurePlugin' has already been declared
//      Azure.js        //
//       v.1.1.0        //
//     OFFICIAL by      //
//    Alex and Anvay    //
//////////////////////////

//THESE ARE SUBJECTED TO CHANGE. 

//functions starting with $$ are helper functions mostly not intended for use

class AzurePlugin {
  constructor(name, invocname, by, ver, desc, funcs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = by;
    this.version = ver;
    this.description = desc;
    this.run = funcs;
    this.invocation = invocname.replaceAll(/\W/g, "");
  }
  info(log = true) {
    if (log) {
      $log(`${this.name} ${this.version}, by ${this.author}. ${this.description}`);
    }
    return {
      name: this.name,
      nwname: this.invocation,
      author: this.author,
      version: this.version,
      description: this.description,
      logged: `${this.name} ${this.version}, by ${this.author}. ${this.description}`
    };
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
I loaded script.js twice. Thanks to Jaromanda X!

Comment: you load `https://azurejs.alexdacoder.repl.co/script.js` twice

Comment: Wow, I'm so dumb. Thank you.